# Table max 3 <td> loop in other tr

Tags: php, html, html-table

How to make it like only 3 offers in row NOW I have one row and all offer is in one line I just want to to show max 3 td in tr and loop.

```
if(count($offer_list['item']) > 0)
{
   $main_content .= '<table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" width=30>';
   foreach($offer_list['item'] as $item)
   {
     $main_content .= '<td class="shop">
     <a class="shop" style="display: block;" href="/shop/item/id/'.$item['id'].'">
     <center><img src="item_images/'.$item['item_id'].'.gif"><br><font color="white"><b>'.$item['name'].'</font></b><font color="red"> <b> '.$item['points'].' points</font></b>';
     if(!$logged)
     {
       $main_content .= '<p><b><a href="/account">[Login to buy]</a></b>';
     }
     else
     {
       $main_content .= '<br><b><font size=1 color="white">Your points balance is: '.$user_premium_points;
       $main_content .= '<br><font color="white"> <fieldset class="shop"><legend>DESCRIPTION</legend>'.$item['description'].'</fieldset></font><br><font color="white"><b> [Click to buy] </b></font></form> </a></center></td>';
     }
     $main_content .= '';
   }
  $main_content .= '</tr></table>';
}
```

> 

Comment: possible duplicate of [3 shop offers in row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22236521/3-shop-offers-in-row)

Comment: If you don't get any answers to your question, try to improve them by giving more information, rather than to post the same question again!

Comment: what i can more i think no more intrested :S and i need fix this problem asap

Comment: I don't really want to but ... you just have to count ... 1, 2, 3 .. next row ... right?

Comment: i have like 12 offers and i wannt to sort them in max 3 in line then next row under

Comment: I really don't understand your question. +1 to the dupe

Comment: now my script show all td in one line i wanna to do only max 3 td then  close tr and next tr with 3 td

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$row_count = 1;

$main_content .= '<table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" width=30>';
  foreach($offer_list['item'] as $item) {

    // Check, if we are at position "1". If so, start new row
    if ($row_count === 1) { $main_content .= '<tr>'; }

    $main_content .= '<td class="shop"><a class="shop" style="display: block;" href="/shop/item/id/'.$item['id'].'">
     <center><img src="item_images/'.$item['item_id'].'.gif"><br><font color="white"><b>'.$item['name'].'</font></b><font color="red"> <b> '.$item['points'].' points</font></b>';
    if(!$logged) {
      $main_content .= '<p><b><a href="/account">[Login to buy]</a></b>';
    }
    else {
      $main_content .= '<br><b><font size=1 color="white">Your points balance is: '.$user_premium_points;
      $main_content .= '<br><font color="white"> <fieldset class="shop"><legend>DESCRIPTION</legend>'.$item['description'].'</fieldset></font><br><font color="white"><b> [Click to buy] </b></font></form> </a></center></td>';
    }


    // Check, if we we are at position "3". If so, end row. (set position back to 1)
    // Otherwise increase position with one level.
    if ($row_count === 3) { 
      $row_count = 1;
      $main_content .= '</tr>';
    }
    else {
      $row_count++;
    }
  } // end foreach


// This is code for filling the "blank" table cells, if you don't have exactly some item count / 3 = 0
if ($row_count !== 3) {
  for ($i=0; $i<=(3-$row_count); $i++) {
    $main_content .= '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
  }
  $main_content .= '</tr>';
}
$main_content .= '</table>';
```

PS: `<center>` is deprecated or more to say not valid HTML anymore.